# Trying to rewrite Access query in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, ms-access

I am trying to re-write this query which I didn't originally write. It was originally created in Access 2000.

```
UPDATE DISTINCTROW NewEx
     INNER JOIN NewIm
     ON NewEx.Number = NewIm.[7]
     SET NewEx.Response = [4] ****
```

From what I understand from T-SQL this should do the same thing.

```
UPDATE NewEx 
SET  NewEx.Response = NewIm.[4] 
FROM NewEx
INNER JOIN NewIm ON NewEx.Number = NewIm.[7]
```

**** I can't understand that you don't have to specify the table name for the join in Access but this totally works.

I had a side question, is there any machine assisted way to convert these queries? A lot of the things I am running into from Access are basically unreadable.

Comment: I don't understand asterisked comment - table names are specified for the join `NewEx INNER JOIN NewIm`.

Answer (score 0):

Your rewritten query is fine.  You might introduce table aliases and just use `JOIN` for a more concise version:

```
UPDATE ne
    SET Response = ni.[4] 
FROM NewEx n JOIN
     NewIm ni
     ON ne.Number = ni.[7];
```